# No resource found that matches the given name in eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, string

```
Here is my code: 
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_3_Front Kick/ Round Kick/ Side Kick"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />  <-- This line is an error
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_4_Front Kick/ Jab/ Cross/ Back Leg Round Kick"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />   <-- This line is an error
```

The two lines with the arrows that say "This line is an error" are the lines that have the error that says that no resources are found that match the given name. Is there a way that I can fix this error?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here, just an error and a small sample of what is presumably a larger project.

Comment: I was wondering how I could fix the error with my strings.  @IMSoP

Comment: Provide a valid resource instead of one that doesn't exist.

Comment: check your targetsdk if that probably causes an error

Answer (score 0):

1. Try cleaning the project.
2. If it doesnt work, remove those lines and set textsize as 18sp (size of Medium)

Answer (score 0):

Clean the Project, Try Fixing Project Properties, make sure your target sdk supports the attribute